# Binary pattern matching - Can I extract the numbers out of "/word/number/word/number"

Tags: erlang, elixir

I know how to do this with regular String operations, but I'm curious if it's possible to match in one step.

Let's say I have `accounts/123123/order/234234234`. It's from an external source, so while I know that `accounts/` and `/order` are always fixed length/value, the numbers might not always be a fixed length. Is there any way to do binary pattern matching here? Or anything better than a few String operations?

Answer (score 7):

> if it's possible to match in one step

We can only pattern match when we know the sizes of all the left pieces. As far as I'm aware, this can't be done as **one** pattern match.

> anything better than a few String operations?

What about just one String operation?

```rb
iex> tag = "accounts/123123/order/234234234"
iex> ["accounts", account, "order", order] = String.split(tag, "/")
iex> account
"123123"
iex> order
"234234234"
```

Regex is also a good option

```rb
iex> tag = "accounts/123123/order/234234234"
iex> regex = ~R{^accounts/(?<account>\d+)/order/(?<order>\d+)$}
iex> Regex.named_captures(regex, tag)
%{"account" => "123123", "order" => "234234234"}
```

Comment: If we are positive that the length of order id does not exceed _some_ finite number, we surely can; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you cannot do with a bit of metaprogramming :)

```rb
defmodule AccOrd do
  @input "accounts/123123/order/234234234"

  for acc <- 1..42 do
    def match(<<"accounts/", acc :: binary-size(unquote(acc)),
                "/order/", ord :: binary>>), do: {acc, ord}
  end

  def test, do: match(@input)
end

AccOrd.test()
#⇒ {"123123", "234234234"}
```

Here we have basically built `42` clauses of `match/1` function. One of them would match your input and voilà.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the very same way I successfully pattern-matched [latitude and longitude](https://github.com/amotion-city/lib_lat_lon/blob/a509f43926b166d52c3acd669b1e310d8f71aa86/lib/lib_lat_lon/data/coords.ex#L122-L145) from gps location given as fancy string returned by G (`"41°23´15.59868˝N"`.)

Answer (score 0):

Other options...

In erlang:

```
~$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> binary:split(<<"accounts/123123/order/234234234">>, <<"/">>, [global]). 
[<<"accounts">>,<<"123123">>,<<"order">>,<<"234234234">>]
```

In elixir:

```
~$ iex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> :binary.split("accounts/123123/order/234234234", "/", [:global])
["accounts", "123123", "order", "234234234"]
```

With elixir regexes:

```
iex(3)> Regex.scan( ~r{[^/]+}, "accounts/123123/order/234234234") |> List.flatten() 
["accounts", "123123", "order", "234234234"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something easy to read, you may convert the binary to list and use the io_lib:format/2 function:

```
1> Tag = <<"accounts/123123/order/234234234">>.
<<"accounts/123123/order/234234234">>
2> {ok,[ACC,ORD],_} = io_lib:fread("accounts/~d/order/~d",binary_to_list(Tag)).
{ok,[123123,234234234],[]}
3>
```